# Error while running after publishing the asp.net core project into Azure free account

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a free account in Azure. I created a  simple project without database and published in Azure and it is running fine in Azure

But after that I created another project with database  and I published the following way

- select project->publish->appservice->create new.
- select create profile. Then I give  Appservice name
- create sqldatabase - I given the  database server name , Administrator user name  and admin password , - click ok
- finally I clicked  create button to create Azure sqlDatabase, SQL server,  App Service, then  it has created Appservice successfully
- after  creating  the Appservice,I given  the  database defaultconnection ticked  to use  this connection string at run time, then i clicked save button.
- After that I clicked Publish button  and then when it try run the published file the following error message is being showed.

HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
Common solutions to this issue:
The application failed to start
The application started but then stopped
The application started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

Answer (score 0):

I was calling a function SeedData from program.cs file to create the master file before start the application. But after commenting out it is working fine.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<MvcProj3_1Context>();
        SeedData(context);
    }
    host.Run();
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```